# Convert IFile to XtextResource

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xtext, workbench

I have an eclipse project with Xtext files.I need to find get all the files in the eclipse project to be `XtextResource` in order to find metrics about them. so far,I tried the following things :

1.Iterate all over the list of files in the project and got them as `IFile` .but I cant convert `IFile` to `XtextResource`.

2.I success get `XtextResource` from **only active page** in `IWorkBenchPage`,so if I can find all the Pages in the project and not only the active (in `IworkBenchPage`)or maybe set all pages in the project as active I think it can work.

this is an example code to what I have done if I have `private static void setResource()
  {
    IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
    IEditorPart activeEditor = page.getActiveEditor();
    if (activeEditor instanceof XtextEditor) {
        XtextEditor xtextEditor = (XtextEditor) activeEditor;
        xtextEditor.getDocument().readOnly((XtextResource resource) -> {

         ResourceHandler.resource = resource;
         return null;
          });
      }
  }`

I am not an expert with all those relations in eclipse and hope somecan can save me here.
thanks!

Comment: Eclipse only has one page per window. Long, long ago there was more that one page but that has not been the case for many years.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work (assuming you create the place where this is used via guice aware extension factory...

```
@Inject
IResourceSetProvider resourceSetProvider;

...
IProject project = file.getProject();
URI uri = URI.createPlatformResourceURI(file.getFullPath().toString(), true);
ResourceSet rs = resourceSetProvider.get(project);
Resource r = rs.getResource(uri, true);
r.load(null)
```

if you dont have guice at your place use

```
ResourceSet rs = IResourceServiceProvider.Registry.INSTANCE.getResourceServiceProvider(uri).get(IResourceSetProvider.class).get(project);
```